# How to view device files from Android Studio - File Explorer is not allowing access

Tags: file, android-studio

I am writing an app that needs to use storage within the app's namespace.  I have chosen to use internal storage but this is not critical.  I am getting the root storage directory using `context.getFilesDir()` and this is resolving to `/data/data/com.boddison.morninglearning/files`.

In order to check my code is doing what I expect, I am trying to access the device files using Android Studio's Device File Explorer but this is not giving me access to the files on the device.

I have checked the Manifest file although for internal storage I don't think any permissions are required.

These are the permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is how it appears in the Device File Explorer.
I would expect to be able to see the files that are on the device.

[image: screenshot showing the File Explorer]

The `build.gradle` file includes this entry in the `android` section:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        customDebug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `build.gradle` needs to have `debuggable true` in order to view the private storage.

The application permissions do not matter at all - because it always has access there.

Comment: I already have `debuggable true` in the `build.gradle` file.  It is in the `android` section.  The relevant code has been added to the original question.